# What are ways for pass parameters from controller after redirect in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redirect

if I write in my controller method:

```
return  "redirect:url";
```

What parameters will be passed to url (it maybe controller method or jsp page)?

Comment: All simple properties in the model. As explained here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting .

Answer (score 88, accepted):

With `RedirectAttributes`, you can pass almost any data to the redirect URL:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someURL", method=GET)
public String yourMethod(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
{
   ...
   redirectAttributes.addAttribute("rd", "rdValue");
   redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("fa", faValue);
   return "redirect:/someOtherURL";
}
```

When you use `addAttribute` to add attributes, this will end up in the target redirect URL. These attributes are used to construct the request parameters and the client (browser) will send a new request to the `redirect URL` with these parameters. With this, you are limited to use String or primitives as your redirect attributes.

And when you use `addFlashAttribute`, these attributes are saved temporarily before the redirect (typically in the session) and are available to the request after the redirect and removed immediately. The advantage of using `flashAttributes` is that, you can add any object as a flash attribute (as it is stored in session).

Comment: Good... I used RedirectAttributes, with request.getParameterMap(). And it works ok to redirect to a new url with all URLs. Example: repassing marketing parameters (utm_source)

Comment: how can we use the above values on "someOtherURL" . Or can we directly use it on html