# Spring access control to page

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I have this Spring+Thymeleaf project, where user must answer to question and after that he/she can fill out a form. 
I want to limit access to this form page (/finish.html), so that you cannot access it directly by typing it to browser and you must have answered correctly to a question.
I have this piece of code,

```js
Long max = difficultyLevels.stream().map(d -> d.getLevel()).max(Long::compareTo).get();
        if (levelId > max) {
            return "redirect:/finish";
        }
```

where I think I should add something to grant access to /finish.html -page. But how I do it?

Answer (score 0):

A redirect causes a new client request. So if you want to protect the /finish endpoint securely there are a few strategies:

You can place a value on the session that you can check in the /finish controller before you render the page.

You could also use redirect attributes to pass some sort of encrypted token and check that in the finish controller. See [What are ways for pass parameters from controller after redirect in spring mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266427/what-are-ways-for-pass-parameters-from-controller-after-redirect-in-spring-mvc).

You could also use a forward instead of a redirect. You can add data to the servlet request as described here: [Spring forward with added parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585216/spring-forward-with-added-parameters). This may not work for you as it won't change the browser url.