# Calling a method of same controller inside another method of same controller in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to call a method inside a method. Both the methods are present inside same controller.

Here is my first method

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/getDonationDetails" , method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
    public String getDonationDetails() throws IOException {
        return "redirect:/getPaymentDetails?  msg=msg";
    }
```

Here is getPaymentDetails method

```
     @RequestMapping(value="/getPaymentDetails", method={RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
     public String getPaymentDetails(@PathVariable String msg){
         System.out.println("message is" + msg);
         return "success";
     }
```

Both methods are present inside same controller. But I am not able to call getPaymentDetails method. Can anyone tell how to call getPaymentDetails method from getDonationDetails method?

Comment: See Plog's answer and this then this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19269653/3959856

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to redirect. You can just call the method:

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/getDonationDetails" , method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
    public String getDonationDetails() throws IOException {
        return getPaymentDetails("msg");
    }
```