# how to save data when redirect to another page

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I use teamleaf and springboot.

When a new user is created, he is redirected to another page on which this user can create a card. The problem is that when forwarding, data about users is lost. That is, the card does not know who its creator is.

```
@Controller
public class PersonController 
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/addPerson"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String savePerson(Model model, 
                             @ModelAttribute("personForm") PersonForm personForm) {
    
        String firstName = personForm.getFirstName();
        String lastName = personForm.getLastName();
        double money = personForm.getMoney();
    
        if (firstName != null && firstName.length() > 0 //
                && lastName != null && lastName.length() > 0) {
          Person   newPerson = new Person(firstName, lastName, money);
            personService.save(newPerson);
    
            return "redirect:/addKonto";
        }
    
        model.addAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage);
        return "addPerson";
    }
```

Kontocontroller

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/addKonto"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveKonto(Model model, //
                            @ModelAttribute("kontoForm") KontoForm kontoForm) {

        String kontoName = kontoForm.getKontoName();
        double moneyInKonto = kontoForm.getMoneyInKonto();

        if (kontoName != null && kontoName.length() > 0) {
            Konto newKonto = new Konto(kontoName, moneyInKonto);
            kontoService.save(newKonto);

            return "redirect:/personList";
        }
```

user and card have a one-to-many relationship

```
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private double money;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE,
            CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<Konto> kontos = new HashSet<>();


public class Konto {
    private String kontoName;
    private double moneyInKonto;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_fk_id")
    private Person person;
```

how can I save user data when I go to another page, as well as save both the user and the card?

Answer (score 1):

I guess an admin is adding the users and managing their cards. In this case you can use `RedirectAttributes` in order to pass the newly created user ID to the new page.

Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19269653/869793

It may also help you to pass the attributes directly through the URL.