# how to redirect the same page in spring with ModelAndView in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to redirect the same page after clicking the edit customer button. I tried to do it this way but it gives me error.

Controller.java

```js
package cap.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import cap.dao.CapDao;
import cap.model.Customer;

@Controller
public class UpdateController {

    @Autowired
    private CapDao customerDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/update/{codicefiscale}")
    public ModelAndView findCustomerByCodicefiscale(ModelAndView model, @PathVariable("codicefiscale") String codicefiscale)
            throws IOException {

        List<Customer> listCustomer = customerDao.findCustomerByCodiceFiscale(codicefiscale);
        model.addObject("listCustomer", listCustomer);
        model.setViewName("updatecustomer");

        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/updatecustdet", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView updateCustomer(@RequestParam("codicefiscale") String codicefiscale, @RequestParam("cognome") String cognome,
            @RequestParam("nome") String nome, @RequestParam("datanascita") String datanascita, @RequestParam("indirizzo") String indirizzo, 
            @RequestParam("numerotelefono") String numerotelefono, @RequestParam("email") String email, ModelAndView mv) throws ParseException {

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setCodicefiscale(codicefiscale);
        customer.setCognome(cognome);
        customer.setNome(nome); 
        customer.setDatanascita(datanascita);
        customer.setIndirizzo(indirizzo);
        customer.setNumerotelefono(numerotelefono);
        customer.setEmail(email);

        int counter = customerDao.updateCustomer(customer);

        if (counter > 0) {
            mv.addObject("msg", "Record di " + customer.getCognome() + "   " + customer.getNome() + " successfully updated");
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/update/{codicefiscale}");
        } else {
            mv.addObject("msg", "Error!");
        }

        mv.setViewName("updatecustomer");

        return mv;
    }
    
    
}
```

As you can see, I added the redirect to the same page along with the update message after updating the customer information via the following line:

return new ModelAndView("redirect:/update/{codicefiscale}");

The error is as follows:
Model has no value for key 'codicefiscale'

What do you suggest me to do? thank you all

Comment: `{codicefiscale}` is a placeholder for a path variable, you have to append an actual value instead of the variable name, e.g `return new ModelAndView("redirect:/update/someValue");`, in your case the value is already contained in a variable: `return new ModelAndView("redirect:/update/"+codicefiscale);`

Comment: @roookeee Thank you, it works. If I also want to add the update message, what should I do? Because this way it only returns me to the same page, without the message.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266427/what-are-ways-for-pass-parameters-from-controller-after-redirect-in-spring-mvc) for example.