# Passing an parameter from controller to view

Tags: spring-mvc

I was making a spring mvc project, when I tried to pass an url param from the controller to the view. I tried to do with with `return "/passChange?error=true";`. That does not work tho and I am out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
model.addAttribute("error");
```

Comment: I want to pass the param trough the url, like in the example. How can I do that?

Comment: In normal scenario like passChange as View name, this wouldn't work. 
If /passChange is url for another controller mapping then it would work provided you use forward:/ 
Haven't tried it this way. Generally we use RedirectAttributes

Answer (score 0):

Use redirect instead.

```
return "redirect:/passChange?error=true"
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19269653/6572971)

Comment: Well, I did this now: `redirectAttributes.addAttribute("error", true); return "redirect:/passChange";` but it still gives me a 404 not found

Answer (score 0):

Use `model.addAttribute("error");` and watch this video to access its value through Javascript (when using Thymeleaf): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kapEh7DcnYs

In summary, use a similar Javascript method to this one:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    /*<![CDATA[*/
      let errorModelAttribute = /*[[${error}]]*/ null;
      addOrReplaceParameterInURL("error", errorModelAttribute);
    /*]]>*/
  });
</script>
```

The method addOrReplaceParameterInURL (which adds the attribute read to the URL) would be the following:

```js
function addOrReplaceParameterInURL(paramName, paramValue) {
  let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  searchParams.set(paramName, paramValue);
  window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + "?" + searchParams.toString();
}
```